# returning the number of columns in a row that are zero in mysql

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have a table that contains amongst other things a datetime column, and 4 other columns that contain either a zero or a number. I would like to return how many columns in a row contain a zero in mysql.

for example

1_datetime      0  2  5  0

2_datetime      5  6  3  0

I would like for each datetime to know how many columns have zeros in

so i want

1_datetime    2

2_datetime    1

thanks

Comment: Surely you tried some SQL yourself that didn't work? Could you post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to sum negated values:

```
SELECT datetime, (!a) + (!b) + (!c) + (!d) AS zero_count
  FROM table
. . . .
```

Operator `!` returns 1 if operand is 0, 0 if operand is non-zero, and `NOT NULL` if operand is `NULL`.

Parenthsis added because adding `+` have higher precedence over negation.

Comment: @srh You have to be sure you haven't NULL values cause you'll get NULL instead of count.

Comment: i just have a zero value or a reading so it works perfectly thank you

Comment: @Kondybas ... "returns `NOT NULL` if operand is `NULL`" ...?  Negating null is still null.

Comment: I've just paste an official manual: `Evaluates to 1 if the operand is 0, to 0 if the operand is nonzero, and NOT NULL returns NULL`